# Magento 2.2.0 checkout issue

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, third-party-module

I need help with my Magento 2.2.0 theme, I setup a new theme based on blank theme. Then I try to install IWD one page checkout extension and it seems that this extension is not work anymore there, I mean there is not any style.

Someone can help me with a idea or something?

Thank you very much

Like this is my onecheckout page

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

style dosnt imported.
try deploy and upgrade then clear cache.
also check console if the js or css is not working because of file permission.

Comment: I check everything there, no errors in console, no errors on log files

Comment: can you share the url?